# Div class not applying css style

Tags: html, css

My css class is not applying the style yet I have imported the css file. What might be the issue?
 Here is the code:

```css
.edubtn{
background-color: #862165;
border: 0;
padding: 2 10px;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
.edubtn:hover{
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="edubtn" onclick="show()" >ORDER</div>
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Oooooo.. You're gonna have to share your `show`  method.

Comment: Try turning off caching temporarily in the development console, under the network tab?

Comment: Have you import the css file?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Can you maybe post a full example (from `<html>` to `</html>`) that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 5):

The only thing wrong with your css is you need to fix the padding attribute:

```
.edubtn{
background-color: #862165;
border: 0;
padding: 2px 10px;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
```

Rememeber if there is an error above this class, the css parser will skip the current block until the next working block.

Comment: Precise observation!

Answer (score 1):

Hey found the problem: I had put my css inside another (@media screen) brackets

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
.attachchild{
width: 90%;
margin-top: 20px;

}
.edubtn{
background-color: #862165;
border: 0;
padding: 2px 10px;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
.edubtn:hover{
color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine, 
the background color is dark purple which is = to saying `background-color: #862165;` 
the text color is white which is = to saying `color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);`
I run your code and I did a `<h2>` with the same style and it works

> HTML Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Beep-Boop</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2 class="something"> Something..</h2>
<div class="edubtn" onclick="show()" >ORDER</div>
</body>
```

> Style CSS :

```
.something{
background-color: #862165;
border: 0;
padding: 10px;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
.something:hover{
color: #fff;
}
.edubtn{
background-color: #862165;
border: 0;
padding: 10px;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
.edubtn:hover{
color: #fff;
 }
```